# Ignore features with std=0 when z-scoring in seaborn's clustermap()

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, data-science, normalization

The data I'm using to create heatmaps with seaborn's `clustermap()` function sometimes has features with standard deviation `std = 0`.

This prompts a `ValueError: The condensed distance matrix must contain only finite values` when using the function's argument `z_score = True` for normalization.

Is there a way to exclude those features for z-scoring to avoid infinite values in the condensed distance matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the function's `z_score` argument with

```py
sns.clustermap(df, cmap="seismic", method="ward", z_score=True)
```

`zscore()` from `scipy.stats` can be used with a `lambda` function to z-score columns with `std != 0` beforehand.

```py
from scipy.stats import zscore

sns.clustermap(df.apply(lambda col: zscore(col) if col.std()!=0 else col, axis=0),
               cmap="seismic", method="ward")
```